# Simulink and Arduino - Simulink can't read data from arduino pins

Tags: arduino, matlab, simulation

I have a very simple setup depicted by this picture [image]

All I want to do is, using simulink, collect data from pin 8. Simulink model is as follows [image]

However I'm not getting any data, specifically 0. I can WRITE to pins but I can't read from them. I'm running it on external mode, fixed step and discrete. Help please? I want to eventually use it for system identification.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* JerSci, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: @jsotola i'm not expecting 0, I'm expecting 5v or a logic 1 but simulink is giving me a 0, which it shouldn't which is why i'm asking this question. Also, no particular reason for the breadboard, just felt like it would be clearer.

Comment: your post says that you are not getting data, specifically not getting `0` ... a direct connection from 5 V to pin 8 would be the clearest

Comment: please test the arduino using Arduino IDE ... set the state of an LED to the state of pin 8 ... or print the value of pin 8 to the serial monitor ... if it fails then the question is about Arduino and the question belongs here ... if it passes then the question is about Simulink and the question does not belong here

Comment: @jsotola i didn't say i'm not getting 0 I said i'm not getting any data, it gives my ONLY 0. And by common sense alone, pin 8 should be anything but 0.

Comment: I am sorry for not understanding you clearly ... please be aware that both `0` and `1` are data ... also a `1` is not necessarily represented by a `high` ... in an `active low` circuit, a `1` is represented by a `low` voltage and a `0` is represented by a `high` voltage ... what happens if you connect pin 8 to ground?

Comment: @jsotola i'm getting 0 when it's connected to ground and 0 when it's connected to 5v in both cases on simulink

Comment: what have you found? ... is it an arduino problem, or is it a Simulink problem?

Comment: @jsotola it's a simulink problem